# VBA Overflow Error when dividing one cell by another

Tags: vba

The code below is trying to divide Column F by Column E. The code gets the correct answer but I keep getting an overflow error, with the debug highlighting this line:

```
Range("G" & Counter).Value = _
          Range("F" & Counter).Value / Range("E" & Counter). Value * 100
```

An example of a number in Column E: 4,345,367.45
An example of a number in Column F: 41,261.72
The final answer in Column G should also be to two decimal places.

```
Dim End_Row As Long
Dim Counter As Long

End_Row = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(-7,0).Row

Counter = Counter + 1

For Counter = 3 To End_Row

Range("G" & Counter).Value = Range("F" & Counter).Value / Range("E" & Counter). Value * 100

Next Counter
```

Comment: Start by qualifying all your calls to `Range()` with a specific worksheet reference, to ensure you're working with the intended sheet.   Eg `Range("G" & Counter).Value` should be `ws1.Range("G" & Counter).Value`

Comment: Have you checked the actual values in the specific row (i.e. counter) that is causing the problem. If you hover over `counter` in debug it should tell you the row number. Alternatively, it might be worth putting in an error trap then report the values to debug when there's an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Dim End_Row As Long
Dim Counter As Long, vF, vE

End_Row = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-7, 0).Row

For Counter = 3 To End_Row
    With ws1.Rows(Counter)
        vE = .Columns("E").Value
        vF = .Columns("F").Value
        
        If IsNumeric(vE) And IsNumeric(vF) Then           'check numeric
            If vE > 0 Then                                'E value is not zero
                .Columns("G") = Round(vF / vE * 100, 2)
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next Counter
```